# Sitecore 9.1 XDB migration issue with Mongo db connection

Tags: xdb, mongodb, migration

I have:

- Sitecore 9.1
- Sitecore 8.2
- MongoDB 3.4
- xDB Data Migration Tool 2.1

I'm trying migrate analytics, I configured tenant and other things by documentations and all looks fine, also Mongo db has "Connection was successfully established." when i run troubleshooter. But when i start "MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration" pipeline i have this error:

```
[Data Exchange] A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ElementAppendingSerializer`1' from assembly 'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.WrapCommandForQueryMessage(ConnectionDescription connectionDescription, Boolean& messageContainsSessionId)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.CreateMessage(ConnectionDescription connectionDescription, Boolean& messageContainsSessionId)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()" }] }. (pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Read Contacts from MongoDB, pipeline step identifier: 58da59cb-2fbb-46ec-9cce-602c8c50b761)
ManagedPoolThread #2 09:19:30 ERROR [Data Exchange]    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor.Count()
   at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.MongoDB.Processors.PipelineSteps.ReadMongoDBDocumentsStepProcessor.LogQueryStatistics(IMongoQuery query, MongoCollection`1 collection, Endpoint endpoint, PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
   at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.MongoDB.Processors.PipelineSteps.ReadMongoDBDocumentsStepProcessor.ReadData(Endpoint endpoint, PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
```

My mongo db connection string is **mongodb://localhost:27017/analytics**, this connection string work fine for sitecore 8.2.

Might be someone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that it's trying to load `MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.4.4.0`. It seems that on your Sitecore instance this DLL has somehow been downgraded incorrectly. You need to make sure MongoDB version **2.6.1.0** is referenced.

Check that all your nuget packages are not downgrading or upgrading Sitecore's default DLL's. You can find the default assembly list on the "Assembly list" link [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Initial_Release.aspx).